# Нужно ли выделить запятыми "например" в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

Нужно ли выделить запятыми "например" в данном предложении?

*Всё у вас в Англии маленькое. Вот **например** это здание в Америке было бы в 10 раз больше.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выделить нужно:

*Вот, например, это здание в Америке было бы в 10 раз больше.*

Если убрать "например", структура и смысл не изменятся.

См.: [**НАПРИМЕР**, *вводное слово*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_444) (Грамота.ру).